# how to take part of a string using explode()

Tags: php, explode

i have sample data like this :

[image]

i want to get integer in the red box. i now i can using `explode()`. but I am confused to apply in my problem. how can i apply explode to my problem?

this my code :

```
$ikan=$_POST['ikan']; //example : Katombo,(30 basket)
$kata=explode("(", $ikan);
```

Comment: do a echo explode(" ",$kata[1]);

Comment: A regex would probably be better. You just want an integer, or an integer in `()`s, or an integer preceding `basket`? `\d` is an integer. https://regex101.com/r/1yW54y/1/ and see `preg_match` documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use explode two times after we explode the first array.

**CODE**

```
$ikan= 'Katombo,(30 basket)';
$kata= explode(" ", explode("(", $ikan)[1])[0];
echo $kata;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
30
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**
If you want to loop it and use regex. you can use the ff:

```
$ikan= array('Katombo,(30 basket)', 'Layang,(0 basket)', 'Loka-loka, (0 basket)', 'Tongkol, (0 basket)');
$kata = array();
foreach($ikan as $value){
     $kata[] = explode(" ", explode("(", $value)[1])[0];
}
```

Using `preg_match_all` and `regex`

```
$ikan= array('Katombo,(30 basket)', 'Layang,(0 basket)', 'Loka-loka, (0 basket)', 'Tongkol, (0 basket)');
$kata = array();
foreach($ikan as $value){
    preg_match_all("/(\d+)/", $value,$num);
    $kata[] = $num[0][0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<?php 
$ikan='Katombo,(30 basket)'; //example : Katombo,(30 basket)
$kata=explode("(", $ikan);
$baskests = explode(" ", array_pop($kata));
echo $baskests[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all integer values in one array... i have added some more in @bluetree answers Try this:-

```
$array = array('Katombo,(30 basket)','Layang,(0 basket)');
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $kataArray[]= explode(" ", explode("(", $value)[1])[0];
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($kataArray); die;
```

Comment: i am not get what you are trying to say @chris85

Comment: see the question of iqbal he clearly mentions he wants integer values @chris85

Comment: Yes, I see, this answer doesn't have anything to do with integers though. See https://3v4l.org/a1O4J

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
<?php
$ikan = str_split('Katombo,(30 basket)');
print_r($ikan);
echo $ikan['9'].$ikan['10']
```

//and the seconde method.

```
  foreach ($ikan as $value){
            if (is_numeric($value)){
                  echo $value;
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Why make an array of characters? If the user already knows what position the numbers they can just use them as is. https://3v4l.org/tqXGd

Comment: Easily distinguishable position the numbers.For me.And use it in the second method.